# give multiple where clause an ales

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm thing to do someThing like this

```
SELECT
  start.time  AS startTime,
  finish.time AS finishTime
FROM Train
WHERE _id = 3 AS start,
WHERE _id = 5 AS finish;
```

is there any equivalent in SQL to this, or I have to create two different select statements.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `_id` is your primary key, you can do a nested `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT start.time FROM Train Where _id=3) AS start
,   (SELECT finish.time FROM Train Where _id=5) AS finish
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right, no parentheses there! Thanks for the edit!

Comment: this isn't my real SQL query 
my real query has 10 lines in WHERE clause
so I was trying to avoid using WHERE  twice

Comment: @humazed . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.

Comment: @humazed SQL lets you build multiple solutions to the same problem, making it hard to come up with a real answer without seeing a real query.

Comment: I was trying to make things simple but I have edited my question with the real query

Comment: I want to note that I think this is the correct answer and should be accepted.  I only answered to provide an alternative based on the OPs comment about the `where`, but that is not part of this question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative uses conditional aggregation:

```
select min(case when _id = 3 then time end) as start_time,
       max(case when _id = 5 then time end) as end_time
from t
where _id in (3, 5);
```

Comment: This is very cute, especially the `min` and `max` to deal with multiple `3`s and `5`s without assuming that `_id` is a PK.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 LAG(time, 2, 0) OVER () AS startTime
 time AS finishTime,
FROM Train
WHERE _id = 5
ORDER BY _id;
```

In case you're able to calulate the offset between start and finish time, you can use LAG function to access value from previous row. In case you can't, please provide the full query, or use @Gordon Linoff solution.